# Solving a backwards heat equation using stochastic calculus

Tags: brownian-motion, differential-equations, wienerprocess, markov, parabolic-pde

Given the PDE

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} = 0$$

with condition $F(T,x) = x^2$, one can use the [Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula) to arrive at

$$F(t,x) = E[X_T^2 | X_t = x] = E[ (X_t \pm \sigma(W_T - W_t))^2 |X_t = x] = x^2 + (T-t)\sigma^2$$

where $W_t$ is standard Brownian motion and $X_t$ is the stochastic process satisfying either:

$$dX_t = \pm \sigma dW_t$$

where the $X_t$'s and $W_t$'s are in the filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \{\mathscr F_t\}_{t \in [0,t]}, \mathbb P)$ where $\mathscr F_t = \mathscr F_t^W$.

---

I am supposed to evaluate

$$E[ (X_t \pm \sigma(W_T - W_t))^2 |X_t]$$

and then later plug in $X_t = x$.

Apparently, in evaluating such, I am to use the Markov property to say that

$$E[ (X_t \pm \sigma(W_T - W_t))^2 |X_t] = E[ (X_t \pm \sigma(W_T - W_t))^2 | \mathscr{F_t}]$$

### **Why exactly do we need to use the Markov property?**

I know that $W_T - W_t$ is independent of $\mathscr{F_t}$. I think that $\because X_t \in m \mathscr F_t$, $W_T - W_t$ is independent also of $X_t$.

If I am wrong, why?

If I am right, why is the Markov property needed?

---

The problem seems to be taken from Bjork's Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time. I got the problem from my class notes. Neither Bjork nor Wikipedia seems to use the Markov property

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the form of your equation, we can consider the SDE
\begin{align*}
dX_t = \sigma dW_t, 
\end{align*}
where $W$  is a standard Brownian motion. Since, for $0 \leq t \leq T$,
\begin{align*}
X_T = X_t + \sigma (W_T-W_t),
\end{align*}
based on Feynman–Kac formula, the solution is given by
\begin{align*}
F(t, x) &= E\left(X_T^2 \mid X_t = x\right)\\
&=E\Big(\big[x + \sigma (W_T-W_t)\big]^2 \Big)\\
&=x^2 + (T-t)\sigma^2.
\end{align*}

---

Copied from comment:

> Here, the Markov property is not explicitly employed. However, only with the Markov property, we can convert the conditional expectation w.r.t. $\mathscr F_t$ as the conditional expectation w.r.t. $X_t$, and can express the expectation as a function of $X_t$, which can then lead the solution by the Feyman-Kac formula. See the proof in Section 6.4 of the book Stochastic Calculus for Finance II by Shreve.

Comment: So the Markov property is unnecessary? That's my concern

Comment: The Markov property is already used - the $\mathscr{F}_t$ is replaced by $X_t$.

Comment: What do you mean Gordon? Which part has the replacement?

Comment: This is a big topic. The book by Karatzas and Shreve has a good explanation.

Comment: Gordon, I checked the book. I can't find anything about using Markov property in using the Feynman-Kac theorem. I got the problem in Bjork. According to my class notes, markov property is needed, but Bjork didn't seem to use markov property. I'll edit

Comment: Thanks for providing more background information. I also need more systematic learning.

Comment: Um, okay Gordon. So where did you use Markov property in your answer? Do you see any Markov property in the Bjork book?

Comment: Here, the Markov property is not explicitly employed. However, only with the Markov property, we can convert the conditional expectation w.r.t. $\mathscr{F}_t$ as the conditional expectation w.r.t. $X_t$, and can express the expectation as a function of $X_t$, which can then lead the solution by the Feyman-Kac formula. See the proof in Section 6.4 of the book *Stochastic Calculus for Finance II* by Shreve.

Comment: What do you mean, Gordon? Where would the conditional expectation on $\mathscr F_t$ be?

Comment: Please see the book I mentioned.

Comment: Strange. I didn't see the edit. Thanks

Comment: What I referred was the proof in Section 6.4 of the book Stochastic Calculus for Finance II by Shreve.

Comment: Yeah I saw it. Checking out book now